# yii2 DetailView template/layout without values

Tags: php, yii2, detailview

I have a little problem in yii2 framework.

1. I have DetailView widget

   ```
                   <?= DetailView::widget([
                       'model' => $table_1,
                       'attributes' => [
                           'year',
                           'table_zs_field_1',
                           'table_zs_field_2',
                           'table_zs_field_3',
                           'table_zs_field_4',
                           'table_zs_field_5',
                           'table_zs_field_6',
                           'table_zs_field_7',
                           'table_zs_field_8',
                           'table_zs_field_9',
                           'table_zs_field_10',
                           'table_zs_field_11',
                           'table_zs_field_12',
                           'table_zs_field_13',
                           'table_zs_field_14',
                           'table_zs_field_15',
                           'table_zs_field_16',
                           'table_zs_field_17',
                           'table_zs_field_18',
                           'table_zs_field_19',
                       ],
                   ]) ?>
   ```
2. If i write this to code I'll see a DetailView widget with names of fields(get from model) and values.
3. Problem: I want to hide values and show only names of fields from model and in next time hide names and show only values. Anybody know ?

Comment: you might want to specify what one two and three are.

Comment: what do u mean by "in next time hide names and show only values"?

Answer (score 1):

Change the $template property of the Detailview.
The Default is

```
$template = '<tr><th>{label}</th><td>{value}</td></tr>'
```

Adding

```
'template'=>'<tr><th>{label}</th></tr>' ,
```

to the config array of your DetailView should show only the names of the fields.
Adding

```
'template'=>'<tr><td>{value}</td></tr>',
```

should show only the value.

See the [corresponding section in the Documentation of DetailView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-detailview.html#$template-detail).